# I can't ping google, local ping is okay, resolv.conf is okay

Tags: linux, ping, vmware-player, debian-wheezy

I use Debian7 image under VMware player for Windows 7.
All was okay. Pinging google was okay.
But after resuming the Linux machine, something happened with network connection.
After some playing with settings, uninstalling/installing VMware, ping to my local network is okay again.
I can ping my gateway router 192.168.0.4.

Trying to ping google I got:

```
       PING www.google.com (74.125.205.104) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

And silence.
As you see google's IP is found.
But "ping 74.125.205.104" does not work.
Ping to my dns ip also does not work.

My /etc/resolv.conf is as follows:

```
    domain Dlink
    search Dlink
    nameserver 188.162.32.74
    nameserver 94.25.128.74
```

route -n

```
    Kernel IP routing table
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
    0.0.0.0         192.168.0.4     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
    192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

I don't know what second line above means.
My /etc/network/interfaces is as follows:

```
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

    iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.31
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.4
    allow-hotplug eth0
    auto eth0

    iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.30
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.4
    wpa-ssid "DIR-300NRU"
    wpa-psk "....."
    auto wlan0
```

I use eth0. wlan0 is down. My gateway is on another device
Any ideas please?

Comment: Your default gateways is out of your wired connection - is it plugged in, or are you using wifi?

Comment: I use eth0. wlan0 is down. My gateway is on another device.

Comment: Please use [`iproute` rather than `net-tools`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93412/difference-between-ifconfig-and-ip-commands/93461#93461). Got what you meant anyhow.

Comment: If you can ping the gateway, then it's not likely first hop link issues. Try tracerouting to Google, or pinging whatever host is directly behind the hypervisor (i.e., the hypervisor's gateway). What do you mean by "DNS IP" anyhow?

Comment: Seems like you are able to ping on your local network, but not off it.  If the routing is going in the right direction, that would suggest NAT has gone awry on the router.  This doesn't seem likely unless there was some sort of MAC/IP address conflict, so we must confirm routing first.  The traceroute suggested by @pilona will tell us.

Comment: There is no iproute on my Debian image. And I can't install it now without internet. I can't ping IP addresses of nameservers of /etc/resolv.conf. Okay. Thank you. I took fresh Debian image, which works okay. It seems I have to repeat my installations.